# Cannot select person from Contact List in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, abpeoplepickerview

I realize this question has been asked prior but nothing mentioned in those threads worked.  Many seemed to have the issue because the delegate was set in viewDidLoad but as you can see from the below, that is not where I am setting mine.  The "Cancel" operation DOES work so the delegate works but not for actually selecting.

Protocol declared:

```
@interface MyTrackDetailsTVC () <UITextFieldDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate>
```

Instance variable defined:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker;
```

Process initiated from a button tap:

```
- (IBAction)importContactTapped:(UIButton *)sender
{
    self.picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];

    self.picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:self.picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Cancel method works just fine:

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker

{
    [[peoplePicker presentingViewController]dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Selection method never called (verified with break points).

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    NSString *fName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    NSString *lName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    NSData *imgData = (__bridge_transfer NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageData(person);

    self.nameField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ %@",fName,lName];
    self.phoneField.text = lName;

    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];

    [[peoplePicker presentingViewController]dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `peoplePickerNavigationController:didSelectPerson:property:identifier:` delegate method is called when a specific property on a contact is selected. If you want to know when a contact is selected, use the `peoplePickerNavigationController:didSelectPerson:` delegate method.

```
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    NSString *fName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    NSString *lName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    NSData *imgData = (__bridge_transfer NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageData(person);

    self.nameField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@ %@",fName,lName];
    self.phoneField.text = lName;

    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];

    [[peoplePicker presentingViewController]dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks for catching that!

Comment: @rmaddy how to call both ?